# FullCalendar Add Icon with myID

Tags: fullcalendar

in the resources I would like to add an icon with an ID inside that I can pass on.
I tried with resourceLabelContent but it doesn't work for me

```
resourceGroupField: 'mygroup',
resourceColumns: [
  {
    labelText: 'Unità',
    field: 'title',                              
  },
  {
    labelText: 'Telefono',
    field: 'Tel',                   
  },
],
resources: {
  url: 'fetch-resource.php',
  method: 'POST',  
}, 
resourceLabelContent: function (arg)
  {        
    return { arg.resource.title + "'<i class="fas fa-users">'+arg.resource.myid+'</i>'"};
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in part .... I modified the JS schduler so, in this way it puts the icons in the resources

```
  ResourceRow.prototype.renderGutterHtml = function() {
    var html, i, j, ref;
    html = '';
    for (i = j = 0, ref = this.depth; j < ref; i = j += 1) {
      html += '<a href="#" class="far fa-envelope m-1 text-info sendMail"/></a>';
    }
    html += '<span class="fc-expander-space">' + '<a href="#" class="fas fa-chart-bar m-1 text-danger graphStat" color=red></a>' + '</span>';
    return html;
  };
```

then with "resourceRender" I go to assign the data-id, but then the click on the icon doesn't work

```
resourceRender: function(resource, cellEls) {                    
    $('.graphStat').attr('data-id',resource.id);
    $('.graphStat').on('click', function(e) {
      alert($(this).data('id'));                
    });
},
```

what am I doing wrong

Comment: maybe it is not the best solution but at the moment I have found assigning Href and ID on mouse over in the cell.

        resourceRender: function(resource, cellEls) {                    
              cellEls.mouseover(function() {  
              $(this).find(".graphStat").attr('id',resource.id);
              $(this).find(".graphStat").attr('href','javascript:MygraphStat("'+resource.id+'");');                                        
          })
        },